# Passing multiple parameters with onRowKey (p:datatable) in PF3.1

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am looking to pass multiple parameters from the following Primefaces 3.1 p:datatable:

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.carsModel}" var="var" rowkey="#{var.model}" 
              selection="#{tableBean.car}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowClick}"></p:ajax>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Model"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="#{var.model}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Color"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="#{var.randomColor}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I have a situation where I have more than 1 key as primary key, I am using  `rowkey="#{var.model}` but, how to work with multiple primary keys.

I am also using `CarDataModel extends ListDataModel<Car> implements SelectableDataModel<Car>{`  class. Can somebody tell me how to work with?

```
@Override
public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
    //In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey 
    //should be implemented to deal with huge data
    List<Car> cars = (List<Car>) getWrappedData();
    for(Car car : cars) {
        if(car.getModel().equals(rowKey))
            return car;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
    return car.getModel();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to use the composite key instead as row key.

E.g.

```
rowKey="#{car.compositeKey}"
```

Or if you insist in using `SelectableDataModel`:

```
@Override
public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
    List<Car> cars = (List<Car>) getWrappedData();

    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getCompositeKey().equals(rowKey))
            return car;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
    return car.getCompositeKey();
}
```

As to the concrete implementation of `getCompositeKey()`, it's unclear what two primary keys you have and what persistence API you're using. JPA for example has already support for composite keys and so your entity should already support it. But if you're not using JPA for some reason, then here's an example which assumes that both the `model` and the `color` represent the composite key, just to illustrate the idea:

```
public String getCompositeKey() {
    return model + "." + color;
}
```

Or

```
public Object[] getCompositeKey() {
    return new Object[] { model, color };
}
```

Or whatever uniquely represents as composite key based on `Object#equals()` contract.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BalusC,you have always been a great help!!! I removed the CarDataModel and now I am getting this error,  DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled. Can you please help? When I removed selection, it says the same error. But if I removed both the selectionMode and selection attributes then table renders fine but I need selectionMode =single as I am clicking the row and going to next page.

Comment: You need to specify the `rowKey` attribute. Note that this is not the same as `rowkey` as you have in your original code.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? I really need to figure this out.please keep in mind that I am learning..thanks again...

Answer (score 4):

You can write a rowKey with all keys directly:

```
<p:dataTable id="productItemsTable" var="i" value="#{b2BOrdersBean.listProductItems}" 
                rowKey="#{i.id.orderId}_#{i.id.productType}_#{i.id.partId}" 
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{b2BOrdersBean.selectedProductItemRow}">
```

You don't need worry about create a function to solve this problem.

Just type each key in rowKey that it's works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with providing a unique (row)key by extending the base class, initialize it with the properties of the passed object and add an additional Id field with a counter value. Not tried yet but should work with reflection to automize the copy of properties fields. I'm confused why PF did not provide such an implicit mechanism.